# python 3 ,ssh tunnel with sql query using pandas not working

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a problem getting result from mysql database using ssh connection.
The sql statement is correct but why dont i have any data in it ?

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb as db
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


# ssh variabler
host = "192.168.99.101"
localhost = "127.0.0.1"
ssh_username = "user"
ssh_password = "password"
ssh_private_key = '/path/to/key.pem'


# databas variabler
user = "user"
password = "password"
database = "database"


def query(q):
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
            (host, 22),
            ssh_username=ssh_username,
            ssh_password = ssh_password,
            remote_bind_address=(localhost, 3306)
    ) as server:
        conn = db.connect(host=localhost,
                          port=server.local_bind_port,
                          user=user,
                          passwd=password,
                          db=database)
        return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)

begin ="""2018-01-03"""
end = """2018-01-04"""

#run sql query
sql = """select collection_type,sum(order_amount) from pz_orders where order_date between {} and {} and print = 'y' group by collection_type""".format(början,slut)
df = query(sql)

print(df)
```

What i get from return from print statement, It should return some numbers.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [collection_type, sum(order_amount)]
Index: []
```

Comment: I have the same problem I connect but my querry does not return no matter how simple it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the paramiko key in the ssh tunnel:

```
import paramiko
localhost = "127.0.0.1"
ssh_username = "user"
ssh_password = "password"
ssh_private_key = '/path/to/key.pem'

pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(ssh_private_key, password=ssh_password)

# databas variabler
user = "user"
password = "password"
database = "database"


def query(q):
    # use ssh_pkey instead of ssh_password
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
            (host, 22),
            ssh_username=ssh_username,
            ssh_pkey = pkey,
            remote_bind_address=(localhost, 3306)
    ) as server:
        conn = db.connect(host=localhost,
                          port=server.local_bind_port,
                          user=user,
                          passwd=password,
                          db=database)
        return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)

begin ="""2018-01-03"""
end = """2018-01-04"""

#run sql query
sql = """select collection_type,sum(order_amount) from pz_orders where order_date between {} and {} and print = 'y' group by collection_type""".format(början,slut)
df = query(sql)

print(df)
```